# Change default classification label (Azure Information Protection) in Microsoft Office (Outlook, Word, Excel) by user

Tags: azure, microsoft

We have Azure Information Protection (AIP) configured for our organisation, we have 4 labels defined (public, internal, confidential, secret). The default label set for the organization is  to "internal".

Is it possible that a user can change the default setting by themself, e.g. setting the default to "confidential"?

Comment: You want the user to have their own default level for all files they create? Why not just add that person to the right group to get the desired level?

Comment: The question is more if there is a possiblity that the user can decide and do that by themselve.